# Unable to contact server when I SSH into Powershell using an RSA key

Tags: powershell, ssh, active-directory

I am working on a script that logs into a VM connected to my AD to perform some administrative functions. The script will be triggered by an application running on a Linux host. I've installed PowerShell Core and the Windows-Compatibility PowerShell module to allow me to log in via SSH. I can log in successfully and run the my script if I use a password, but if I log in using an RSA key, I get this error when I import AD:

> Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not
>   exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory
>   Web Services running.
>
> - CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADServerDownException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
> - PSComputerName        : localhost

The script on the Linux host looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh ad\\ad-user@windows-host-ip \
    -o IdentitiesOnly=yes \
    -i ./id_rsa \
    "C:\\pwsh\\pwsh.exe -c C:\Users\ad-user\Scripts\ad-management-script.ps1"
```

And the `ad-management-script.ps1` looks something like this:

```
Import-WinModule ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Identity ad-user
```

Like I said before: This runs perfectly if I leave the key off and enter a password, but it hits the error I mentioned above if I use the key.

Other notes: Regardless of which method I use to log in, I get these values from the $env:

```
> $env:username
ad-user
> $env:userdomain
ad
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Maybe try use powershell instead of pwsh? Is that win 2012 box? If so try smth like: powershell -c 'Get-AdUser ad-user'

Comment: I got the same error. I had to use the syntax `powershell -c Get-ADUser ad-user` but I assume that's inconsequential.

Comment: Do you just need an output from Get-ADUser -Identity command ?

Comment: No, that's just a simple example that triggers the error. I'll have several AD administration scripts through this process.

Comment: Ok, but all those tasks are AD related ( need ad module)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

As per brief googling looks like people are getting similar issues with ActiveDirectory module while remoting to Windows machine. Not sure suggested workarounds are applicable to your case though. However there are alternatives for using this module. Try options below and see if any of it works.

**1. In Powershell (not core):**

$user = "someuser"

$searchByUser = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=organizationalPerson)(samaccountname=$user))"

([adsisearcher]$searchByUser).FindOne().Properties

**2. DSQUERY (In CMD, no need for powershell)**

dsquery * -filter "samaccountname=someuser"

**3. NET (in CMD)**

net user SOMEUSER /domain

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the double hop problem. We can not use keys which are used for authentication to remote VM , to authenticate AD server too. There are multiple option which you can use, here is the guide

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.2